# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to execute

Tags: jquery, ajax

I keep getting a 500 Internal Server error when selecting a state from my first drop down. Do you see anything wrong with my ajax call?

```
 function LoadCities() {
        __state = $("ddlState option:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/LoadCitiesByState",
            data: {'state': __state},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                alert("Cities loaded");
            },
            fail: function () {
                alert("Error.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }     



[WebMethod]
public void LoadCitiesByState(string state)
{
    try
    {

        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Value = "0";
        li.Text = "Select One";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = SharedDataAccess.GetCities(state);
        ddlCity.DataSource = dt.Rows[0].Table.DefaultView;
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "ListCity";
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "ListCity";
        ddlkCity.DataBind();
        ddlCity.Items.Insert(0, li);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Rather than flailing around with your JS code, why not look at the server's error log to see what it thinks the problem is?

Comment: something is wrong with the server side

Comment: You will need to load the ddl on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL is funky:

```
url: "Default.aspx/LoadCitiesByState"
```

does not look correctly formatted, if anything it might be something like this (referring to your root):

```
url: "/Default.aspx?LoadCitiesByState"
```

Then again I am just making an educated guess here, as you don't give us much info on the error or further debug.